# Can I remove admin rights from an OS X account without using the command line?

Tags: macos, user-account, administrator

I gave my everyday OS X user account admin rights whilst trying to get a code project working.

I now no longer need admin rights. However, when I log in using either my everyday account *or* my admin account, the “Allow user to administer this computer” checkbox for my everyday account is both selected and disabled, so that I can’t remove the admin rights from my account. (I did click on the padlock icon and unlock it using my everyday account password first.)

[image]

Is there a way to enable the checkbox, or another way to remove admin rights for this account?

I’ve seen how to [do so on the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105442/os-x-change-admin-user-to-standard-user-with-command-line), but it feels like there should be some way to do this in the GUI.

Comment: Have you verified that the pane is unlocked by clicking on the Padlock in the lower left-hand corner to allow for editing? This is required to edit the page for admins as well.

Comment: @smoooosher: I did!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha — the reason why this option was greyed out is, I think, because I was still logged in under the everyday account.

When I *logged out* of the everyday account, and logged into my admin account (instead of just switching straight to the admin account, leaving my everyday account logged in), *then* the “Allow user to administer this computer” checkbox for my everyday account was enabled, and I could uncheck it.