# Impossible to downgrade admin user -- "Allow user to administer this computer" box greyed out

Tags: permission, user-account, administrator

I am trying to remove the admin right from my personal user account. To do so I created another admin account, but  the checkbox in `System Preferences > Users & Groups` remained greyed out. Then I tried from the root account (screenshot below), to no avail. I also tried to use the command line [with this command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105442/os-x-change-admin-user-to-standard-user-with-command-line),

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -d RemiLePriol -t user admin
```

but it did not work either. I do not know what else to try. Any idea ?
[image: users and groups menu]

Comment: Did you try when logged into the Aurelie Admin account?

Comment: The picture suggests you're trying to demote the RemiLePriol user _while you're logged in as RemiLePriol_. It isn't suprising that macOS won't let you change aspects of the user account from within that same user user account. I agree with benwiggy: try the demotion while you're logged into a different Admin account.

Comment: You are not alone.  I have two administrator users and I can't demote the other one.

Comment: If I create a new admin user (the third one), login to it, logout and then want to demote - no problems.  But for my existing 2nd admin user, I can't demote. I don't know why!

Comment: @benwiggy @DavidSupportsMonica I tried logged in from the Aurelie account, as well as from the root `System Administrator` account (as shown in the picture), with no success.

Comment: I have the same problem but in my machine I'm stuck with an old version of Mac OS (if I update, I loose access to my Nvidia drivers that I need to run the GPU). So it may be a problem with old versions of Mac OS.